# Save grayscale image as mesh file such as stl or ply file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, mesh

Grayscale image can be displayed using `surf` or `mesh` command to show it as a 3D mesh. I hope to save the mesh to the disk as a 3D mesh file. For the mesh, the vertices consists of x-y coordinates and gray value. Does anyone try this?

Example:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
mesh(double(I));
```

Comment: please provide an example image; how do you exactly display the grayscale image as a 3D mesh?

Comment: I add one example to my post.

Comment: You just need something that writes STL files and a code that defines the triangles/squares using vertices. It should be easy once you have that

Comment: Matlab can show the STL, so it means that Matlab generates one mesh from the grayscale image. How can I get the information about the generated mesh from Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stlwrite script provided here

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20922-stlwrite-filename--varargin-

```
I = double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:length(I));
stlwrite('cameraman.stl', X, Y, I );
```

[image: 3D Preview of the generated STL file]